# custom post_type - changing the posts_per_page - not working correctly

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

I am trying to make it so that my custom post_type's will output in my pagination loop on the main page of my Wordpress site X amount of posts. However, it's not working.

Here is my code;

```
<?php if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ); } else if ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'page' ); } else { $paged = 1; }
    $my_query = new WP_Query ( array (
        'post_type' => array ( 'reviews', 'blogtours', 'interviews', 'post' ),
        'posts_per_page'      => array( '1', '5', '0', '0' ),
        'paged'               => $paged, ) );
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
```

I set 'interviews' and 'post' to 0 right now because they don't have any yet. I even tried removing them, thinking you couldn't set a post_per_page to 0 and that didn't work either (removing them from both posts_per_page and post_type).

The only thing that has worked so far is if I change;

```
'posts_per_page'      => array( '1', '5', '0', '0' ),
```

to

```
'posts_per_page'      => 3,
```

As an example. Then, it DOES show 3 posts, but in general from ALL post_types which is what I don't want. I want to be able to have it select from individual post_type. Because the "blogtours" post_type is going to have far more than any other and if I don't limit it to a smaller number, the other post_types will never been seen (unless you go to the front page, but I do a lot of posts per day so even that isn't feasible).

Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an array for posts_per_page from what I have researched. It has to be one number.arw you trying to dump all of these posts out into the same feed or different pages? If different pages, you should separate out the queries. Posts per page is going to limit all of the posts to only show 3 total from the query. It's basically only going to grab 3 no matter what. If you separate out each query on the different posts, you can set the posts per page individually like the way you want. Then I would have a separate array that that you push all the different posts into, that then is fed onto your homepage. Does that make sense? Query on each post type so you can limit the amount of posts you get from the database, then push them into a master array of all of your posts.

Below are your four separate queries, but make sure I have the correct posts_per_page you want.

```
    $post_reviews = get_posts(
        'post_type'      => 'reviews',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 5
    );
    $post_blogtours = get_posts(
        'post_type'      => 'blogtours',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 3
    );
    $post_interviews = get_posts(
        'post_type'      => 'interviews',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 3
    );
    $post_post = get_posts(
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 5
    );

    // Below is where you merge all four arrays
    $all_posts = array_merge($post_reviews, $post_blogtours, $post_interviews, $post_post);

   // Sort through the posts, this might need modification based on your data in the array
    function sortFunction( $a, $b ) {
        return strtotime($a["date"]) - strtotime($b["date"]);
    }
    usort($all_posts, "sortFunction");

    // Here is your loop through each post
    foreach ($all_posts as $post) {
        echo $post;
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to dump them, or paginate them in the same loop on the main page. So like, all of the posts for 'reviews', 'blogtours', 'interviews', 'post' will all be on the same main page (where normally it's just the "post" post_type and instead of just one number when you can usually decide on for "post", I want to be able to specify different numbers for the different post_types. If that makes sense. What you said does make sense, sort of.

Comment: Except 1) would they then all still be ordered by date published (not by each post_type but in general like even if post_type A query was first and most recent post was published say on Monday, but post_type B query was second and its most recent post was published on Wednesday but because query A was first, does that mean that the post published on Monday is above the post on Wednesday? -- Basically, I want everything to work just like it would as if they weren't custom post types except that they are.

Comment: the 2nd thing is, I'm really not great with arrays / these types of queries so I'm not sure how I would separate them out so that they would still paginate together.

Comment: I will add some code for you to the answer with the four separate queries momentarily!

Comment: I have added the queries, I'll send over some more stuff to that answer momentarily as well.